# Store row count or use query to calculate on Primary Key

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

I am curious to know if I should store the row count for an instance number of friends of a user into a separate table or if I should use a query like

```
SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM user_friend WHERE user_id = 20;
```

where user_id is `AUTO_INCREMENTED` `PRIMARY_KEY`

Is querying the `COUNT` each time slower than storing the row account in a separate table?

In my opinion, I shouldn't store the row counts separately as this will lead to `Denormalization` and also some other factors like having to update the row count again and again and fetching the records by joining the tables unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Redundant information in a database is a no-no.

If you have an index (such as the `PRIMARY KEY`) on `user_id` and if there is not thousands of rows for a user, the computing it on the fly is the way to go.

Comment: Consider there is a potential of the table to grow as large as 10,000 of rows, even then, should I consider storing the counts?

Comment: The `COUNT(*)` won't scan 10K rows, only the rows for the user in question.